# restrict(amp) function type

Tags: c++, lambda, gpgpu, ppl, c++-amp

I can create `restrict(amp)` function as follows:

```
auto f = [](int& item) restrict(amp) {item += 1;};
```

And I can use this function in other `restrict(amp)` functions, for example:

```
concurrency::parallel_for_each(av.extent,
    [=](concurrency::index<1> idx) restrict(amp) 
    { 
      f(av[idx]); 
    }
);
```

What type of substituted instead "`auto`" after compilation? I tried to use the "std::function":

```
std::function<void (int&) restrict(amp)> f
           = [](int& item) restrict(amp) {item += 1;};
```

but received a compile error.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the function type in `std::function`'s template argument. Did you try: `std::function<void (*)(int&)restrict(amp)> f = ...`?

Comment: It does not work. Highlights intellisense  error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MSVC, but I've heard before that the compiler, the compiler frontend and the IDE/Intellisense are all separate, not-quite-compatible products, and so it's possible that one complains about something that the other accepts. Caveat emptor.

Comment: Yes, i agree, but also exist compilation error.

Comment: Can you try just `std::function<void (int&)>`, or `void(*)(int&)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of a lambda expression is a closure object, and the type of the closure object is unknowable. You can *only* use `auto` to declare a variable of its exact type.

However, you can **convert** a closure object into a suitable instance of an `std::function`, and if the lambda is non-capturing, you can even convert it to a function pointer. However, this conversion may come at a (significant) cost, so you should prefer using `auto` as much as possible to handle the actual closure type.

The same goes for `bind` expressions.

The relevant standard section is 5.1.2(3):

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type — called the closure type — whose properties are described below. This class type is not an aggregate.

That said, I'm not sure how the special AMP extensions behave in this context, and it's conceivable that AMP-restricted lambdas are *not* convertible to anything else. I'll try and look this up in the AMP specification.

**Update:** Sections 2.2.3 and 2.3 of the [AMP Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/0/E/40EA02D8-23A7-4BD2-AD3A-0BFFFB640F28/CppAMPLanguageAndProgrammingModel.pdf) seem to apply to this question.

Comment: @Milovidov: I see, sorry for that. I'd have to consult the AMP specification (which is freely available, by the way).